# How to create more 2 arguments in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm trying to a build a simple app and the main point is I must use dictionary. I will have data like this in my dictionary:

(key,number,number,number,number)

So below is my code which implements my data.

```
 Dictionary<string,int,int,int,int> states = new  Dictionary<string,int,int,int,int>();
```

I have looked at many sources for how to solve it, but I couldn't find it. 
I get an error that it must have a two arguments.

Can you give me a solution to make a dictionary can hold more than 2 arguments?

Comment: Why not create a class that holds the 4 numbers?

Comment: i think that difficult to implement in my logic app , i have tried it i was getting many stuck , so instead of it , i am trying use dictionary

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class to hold the 4 numbers like this:

```
public class MyData
{
    public int Number1 {get;set;}
    public int Number2 {get;set;}
    public int Number3 {get;set;}
    public int Number4 {get;set;}
}
```

And use it as the dictionary value type like this:

```
Dictionary<string,MyData> states = new Dictionary<string,MyDate>();
```

Here is a code example that adds an item to the dictionary:

```
states.Add("my_key", new MyData { Number1 = 1, Number2 = 2, Number3 = 3, Number4 = 4});
```

To access data for a specific key, you can use:

```
MyData data = states["my_key"];

int number1 = data.Number1;
//...
```

To iterate over all data, you can use a simple `foreach` like this:

```
foreach(var kvp in states)
{
    var key = kvp.Key;

    var data = kvp.Value;

    var number1 = data.Number1;
    //...
}
```

Another alternative for `MyData` would be the [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd414846(v=vs.110).aspx) class. But having your own type is probably better because you can have your own names for the 4 number properties.

Comment: so now , how i can iterate all of my data
and how can i access my data which has an key :my_key:

Comment: You can use a `Tuple<...>` type instead of a custom class like  `MyData`. For example `Tuple<int, int, int, int>` in your case. There you can access the values via `Item1`, `Item2` and so on. The easiest way to create an instance is the static `Tuple.Create`-method

Comment: @Koopakiller, right. I mentioned the `Tuple` based option in my answer but without giving an example.

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the last four integers does not matter, you can use

```
 Dictionary<string, List<int>>
```

By this way, you can get your int list with your string key, and then enumerate the list.

OR you can go with any array type such as

```
 Dictionary<string, int[]>
```